# What is the equivalent of this ternary operator expression?

Tags: javascript, typescript, conditional-operator

I have to use a piece of code that comes from another company project.
Unfortunately, it contains an expression that triggers an error in SonarCloud.
The error is:

> Non-empty statements should change control flow or have at least one side-effect

The colleague that wrote this line is not in the company anymore.

The line that needs to be modified is `xhr.status === 200 ? observable.next(xhr.response), observable.complete()) : observable.error(xhr.statusText);`.

Here is the full code:

```js
  sendMedia(file: File, presignedUrl: string): Observable<Object> {
    return new Observable(observable => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('PUT', presignedUrl, true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          xhr.status === 200 ?
            (observable.next(xhr.response), observable.complete()) :
            observable.error(xhr.statusText);
        }
      };
      xhr.send(file);
    });
  }
```

If this block equivalent to that statement?

```js
if (xhr.status === 200) {
  return observable.next(xhr.response), observable.complete();
} else {
  return observable.error(xhr.statusText);
}
```

Thanks a lot for anyone trying to help!

Comment: `If this block equivalent to that statement?`, well have you tried to test both?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel I can't, we do not have test units on my project.
Moreover, if I don't understand the code, it's hard to write a test for it, that will include all the test cases that I ignore.

Comment: @sp00m I completely agree with you!
I'm not the one wrote this piece of code but I definitely would not have done this way.

Comment: `we do not have test units on my project` you can simply test it by using your application. ---- `Moreover, if I don't understand the code, it's hard to write a test for it` then it's even harder to blindly refactor that piece of code.  ---- `that will include all the test cases that I ignore` Here you're just focusing on a single path, you don't really have to cover all the branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there except return statement

```
if (xhr.status === 200) {
  observable.next(xhr.response);
  observable.complete();
} else {
  observable.error(xhr.statusText);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I wasn't sure about these return statements, for helping me =)